# can i load a program from github during my local anchor tests?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client

I have an anchor program (and typescript client) that I want to test against the [Solend Program](https://github.com/solendprotocol/solana-program-library). Is it possible to load the Solend program locally within "anchor test" without explicitly cloning the repo? eg by just specifying the github url in the Anchor.toml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, see this : https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/manifest#test-validator
essentially you need to configure your anchor toml file, where you set a url which is the mainnet api and the solend program id anchor(version >=0.23) will automatically clone the data account if the account is owned by a bpf upgradeable loader  not only programs you can also add specific program accounts you want to clone, such that when you start your test these programs/accounts will be loaded from genesis